# Concatenate different rows into one in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation, rows

I have this database ("statement") where each word of a sentence is in a different row

```
SENTENCE |  SEQUENCE |  TEXT
    A   |   1       |   MY  
    A   |   2       |   NAME
    A   |   3       |   IS
    A   |   99      |   CARL
    B   |   1       |   MY  
    B   |   2       |   NAME
    B   |   3       |   IS
    B   |   99      |   JUSTINE
```

I would like to do a select where the result is the complete sentence, like:

```
 SENTENCE | TEXT
    A   |   MY  NAME IS CARL
    B   |   MY  NAME IS JUSTINE
```

since I cannot create a new table, I would like to put the command in the select just to have a new column. In each sentence the words are sorted in the column "sequence" and 99 is always the last word of the sentence.

I've tried adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) solution but it didn't work.

Thank you very much

Turi

Comment: The solution you refer to is SQL-Server. MySQL has a whole other SQL syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sentence, group_concat(text order by sequence separator ' ')
from your_table
group by sentence
```